# Using Mocha Test Explorer with VScode when not in default `/test' folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I am currently working on a project where the test files are stored in `/code_tests` instead of the default `/test`. I am trying to avoid having to rename the folder but I can't seem to change the default location for the Mocha Test Explorer.

The project is using Typescript on vscode.

The documentation provides this line of code. `"mochaExplorer.files": "test/**/*.ts"` which I assume would need to be changed to `"mochaExplorer.files": "code_tests/**/*.ts"` but I can't seem to find where to store this command for it to work as intended.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add these to vscode `settings.json`

```
"mochaExplorer.require": "ts-node/register",
"mochaExplorer.files": "code_tests/**/*.ts",
```

Answer (score 12):

Well if you don't have `.vscode` folder in you project structure, create one. And in `.vscode/settings.json` add the following

```
"mochaExplorer.require": "ts-node/register",
"mochaExplorer.files": "tests/**/*.ts",
```

Comment: What added value is this answer providing compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: @Splines: It's best practice to use a settings file local to your workspace than put those in the global settings of vscode. This way your settings can be different in each workspace if you work on several ones on the same computer. I think this answer deserves to be the accepted answer over the other one.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and thought I had configured my `.mocharc.json` file [correctly](https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs). However, I found that I needed to specify the files that I wanted tested as `"spec": "path/to/files/*.extension"` instead of `"files": "path/to/files/*.extension"`.

It appears that `"files"` is an older specification, which seemed to work fine at the command line, but doesn't work for some tools like in VS Code Mocha Explorer.